# Jmeter - Compare/assert multiple data: Data from JSON against data from DB

Tags: jmeter

For the purpose of my task i need to compare Data from JSON against data from DB, but i have few doubts how to build the scenario. My scenario is like:

1 Perform DB query

[image]

Which returns dynamic set like:

```
url secret
https://test1.com/  1234
https://test2.com/  1234
https://test3.com/  1234
```

**Based on this dynamic set, i drive my Loop controller to loop. Here from every single call, different JSON is produced like:**

[image]

```
[
{
    "adminLink": "",
    "BTCAmount": 0,
    "lastName": "test",
    "amount": 1,
    "clientId": "e1d4ab18517711eaa84cfa163eb75a2c",
    "foundingSourceName": "test",
    "secretId": "2938663415",
    "txId": "",
    "mcTxId": "1079249234",
    "paymentAddress": "",
    "result": "transaction timed out",
    "firstName": "test",
    "phoneNumber": "",
    "currency": "USD",
    "refoundAmount": 0,
    "approveTime": 1582543463,
    "email": "",
    "status": 1,
    "timestamp": 1581938595
},
{
    "adminLink": "",
    "BTCAmount": 0,
    "lastName": "test",
    "amount": 550,
    "clientId": "ffe22f34742311eab73f06ed6719cf46",
    "foundingSourceName": "test",
    "secretId": "3096308675",
    "txId": "",
    "mcTxId": "1101155492",
    "paymentAddress": "",
    "result": "transaction timed out",
    "firstName": "test",
    "phoneNumber": "",
    "currency": "USD",
    "refoundAmount": 0,
    "approveTime": 1586355699,
    "email": "",
    "status": 1,
    "timestamp": 1585750862
}   
]
```

2 From this dynamic json, i can extract: mcTxId with:

[image]

3.
For every single mcTxId , i need to perform JDBC query using:

```
select *
FROM affiliate_transaction
WHERE affiliate_id = 1  and mctxid = '${mcTxId_1}'
```

Which result to:

[image]

I managed to solve up to Loop Controller, and extract every single mcTxId, but i am stuck to nested looping logic, and assert each data.

[image]

How can i compare/assert every single `clientId` & `approveTime` between API call(json) and DB query, where their data set is always dynamic?

[image]

Any help is highly appreciated.
Apologies for the long post

Answer (score 1):

1. Change your query to `select client_id
   FROM affiliate_transaction
   WHERE affiliate_id = 1  and mctxid = '${mcTxId_1}'` and store it into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) like `client_id_from_db`

   [image]
2. Use [JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor/) to get the client ID from the API  and store it into a JMeter Variable like `client_id_from_api`

   [image]
3. Once done you should be able to compare 2 JMeter Variables using [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion)

   [image]